# What is this succulent with little orange flowers?

Tags: identification, succulents

A friend gave me this succulent because I thought it looked cool. Can you help me figure out what it is?

[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].

I took some pictures with the flash and some without. The trunk from the base to the tip is about 4 inches. Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks!

Comment: Your plant is not a happy camper.  ID is no problem but the life of this guy is in dire straits.  Please tell us what and how and why and when you; water, fertilize, how much light, what soil is in that pot.  Plants sometimes flower profusely when they sense time is short.  Would like to help that little plant...

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I got the plant two days ago. So the only thing I've done is lightly misted once, and placed in a southward facing window. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I want to save the little guy too D;

Comment: Risco, do get distilled water.  The new picture shows big time salt deposits from tap water.  Wash the little pot and scrub the white deposit off...might make a great starter pot for another small cutting or newbie family member.  What is this black fabric?  Is this landscape fabric you are using for the pictures?

Comment: Stormy, it's actually a cover on my pool table. I tried to move it from the window to get the best picture. I'm going to try to wash it off and repot here later today. I do have a use for the tiny pot, but I'm hopeful that if it still has troubles I can try to prune it. I won't give up on the little guy until I know it's too late. There is a tiny little bit of bright green growth so I am hopeful

Comment: You have major gardener traits, so hang in there! I am overly sensitive to landscape fabric.  This stuff was made only for laying under gravel on top of soil to save the install of gravel from disappearing into the soil.  Not for weeds, not at all!!  I feel silly, of course this is inside and a fine backdrop.  I've pulled up so much of this I think I've become allergic or something!  Glad there is green!  Do you see the white residue on your little pot?  Taste it!  Or not.  That residue is salt from tap water.

Comment: "Another reason for the sides of a leaf to turn brown is a high salt content in the soil. This can either be natural in the soil, such as from living close to the ocean, or this can happen through over fertilizing. If you live near a source of salt water, there will be very little you can do to correct the problem."  Watering with distilled water, transplanting into new soil and new pot... does correct the problem (s).  Soak the empty little pot in vinegar and scrub the residue off.

 http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/environmental/what-causes-brown-edges-on-leaves-of-plant.htm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can't be answered without the images for identification. Please [edit] your post and use the image embedding tool in the editor to provide them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Crassula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjS6N6hz93PAhUiqVQKHeruBf4QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F180214422568354560%2F&bvm=bv.135974163,d.cGw&psig=AFQjCNHATMPZTbk4FJUCPf8BthhqZnfD_g&ust=1476648685543052://)

Does this look like your plant when you first purchased and brought it home?  Looks like it has brown scale and giving up.  There is no GREEN left.  Green means photosynthesis is happening.  Where has this plant been located?  Looks like way too little light.

If you want to try to save this plant, I'd get new potting soil, a new pot (try 4" wide and 2" deep, clay), transplant, make sure it is in a south window out of direct sun or use a grow light.  Wash the leaves very gently in dish soap, very very gently.  Water but don't soak.  Allow a bit of water to drain out of the bottom hole (no rocks, or sand, or gravel at the bottom). Let it just acclimate.  Don't use any fertilize until we see if there is any new growth.  The next step would be to cut those stems back to 2 or 3 inches, removing that frumpy top growth.  Don't mist.  If your succulent (a desert plant that loves dry air, sporadic, shallow showers and incredible drainage, never wet feet/roots and full sun) starts to show life great, otherwise, try again with a new group of these sweet plants.  Do not love them to death.  The number one cause of indoor succulent plant death is too much care. No misting, no watering until the soil is bone dry, plenty of light and once per year a little 'Osmocote' 14-14-14.  Remove the foo foo rocks on the surface of the soil so that you are able to watch 'vital signs', water with distilled water not tap water, no direct sunlight unless acclimated (don't bother with this right now), once per year extended release fertilizer, increase the pot size by an inch no more and transplant only into potting soil when the bulk of that plant quadruples in size from what it is right now.

My measurements are a suggestion only.  I'd need to see more of your plant if it lives.  Have you ever seen those framed, live succulent 'pictures' for mounting on a wall? Massed succulents like yours grown in a shallow frame of soil, once they all grow together and their roots hold the soil and plants to the back of the frame, people hang them in their homes for temporary purposes, definitely cool 'decorations' in the garden as well as creating a 'garden' on top of roofs of livaboard homes. Pretty tough plants and I love groupings of these cute little guys.  They grow up of course and can look very different than when you purchased them.  The cool thing is these succulents are slow growing and make lots of miniature clones of themselves to continue the family.

Comment: So you can see part of my comment above, but to answer where it has been. It was very close to my friends house, outside southward facing. But there is a large tree near there so probably not enough light. I got it five or so days ago now. I do have succulent potting soil that I just got today to replant.i am not too sure what it looked like when she got it. I will try your suggestions and post a picture when I'm done.

Comment: Excellent, more light, fresh soil, distilled water, osmocote fertilizer later.  Did you get a new pot?  Clay, not glazed is best for succulents.  Raise the bottom off the surface it sits upon even if that is a saucer.  No wet feet. Use pebbles, tile pieces. that space between the surface and the bottom of the pot helps drainage and ensures no wet feet.  I see the little bit of new growth that is green, is there anymore?

Comment: Okay so it took me longer than I thought to repot this little guy, but here is what I did. Repotted into succulent soil I got from the store into a new terra-cotta pot. Lightly washing the plant in water containing dish soap. Here's what it looks lik now. Not sure if it looks too much better, but I am hopeful to see how it does.

Comment: https://s22.postimg.org/n106lbhb5/IMG_0045.jpg

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/wmycfcxul/     https://s22.postimg.org/pxrszccip/IMG_0047.jpg   https://s22.postimg.org/e9xr4sndt/IMG_0048.jpg

Comment: Well wonderful!!  Perfect sized pot and my goodness, this feels like waking up in OZ and the black and white turns to color!!  How funny the flowers are actually coloring...how sweet!!  Carry on Risco!!  Very well done!